# オーバーロードされたメソッドの曖昧さを Scala で明示的に解決するには?

Tags: java, scala

Java のライブラリに用意されているオーバーロードされたメソッドを Scala で利用しようとしています。

```java
class X{
  public <E> void f(E... values){ System.out.println(1); }
  public void f(Object value){ System.out.println(2); }
}
```

しかし Scala ではパラメータの型に互換性がある場合、オーバーロードされたメソッドのどれを使って良いか解決することができずコンパイルエラーが発生します。

```scala
val x = new X()
x.f("foo")
```

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method f in class X of type (value: Any)Unit
and  method f in class X of type [E](values: E*)Unit
match argument types (String)
```

呼び出し時のパラメータ部分を `"foo":Object` や `"foo".asInstanceOf[Object]` などにしても状況に変化はありません。回避策としてリフレクションを使用することはできます。

```scala
classOf[X].getMethod("f", classOf[Object]).invoke(x, "foo")  // => 2
```

根本的に、Scala で 2. 側のメソッドを明示的に呼び出すにはどうすれば良いでしょうか?

Java 11.0.2 / Scala 2.12.8

Comment: `Java のライブラリ`の名前を具体的に教えていただくことは可能でしょうか？(一般的に公開されていないライブラリでしょうか？)

Comment: この投稿で対処している具体的な Java ライブラリは argparse4j で、デフォルト値や定数値を設定する部分です。 https://argparse4j.github.io/apidocs/net/sourceforge/argparse4j/inf/Argument.html#setDefault-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 1):

おそらくですが、Scalaから`setDefault(Object value)`のメソッドを呼び出すことはできません。

dotty(Scala 3.x)では、何かしらの方法により、可能になるかもしれません(?)。
https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/5792

とりあえず、妥協案が3つほど考えられます。
(リフレクションで呼び出す方法は質問文に書かれていますので除きました)

**妥協案 1: 他のライブラリの使用を検討する**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315912/best-way-to-parse-command-line-parameters
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112879/scala-command-line-parser-with-subcommand-support

**妥協案 2: `setDefault(E... value)`のメソッドを呼び出す**

こちらのメソッドであれば、以下のようなコードで呼び出すことができる気がします。

```scala
arg.setDefault(Seq("foo"): _*)
```

ただし、ヘルプで表示されるデフォルト値が、以下のような表示になるかと思います。
(余計な`[]`が付いてしまう)

```
(default: [foo])
```

**妥協案 3: Javaでヘルパーclassを書き、Scalaで使用する**

argparse4jのScalaラッパーである[mdekstrand/argparse4s](https://github.com/argparse4j/argparse4j)で使用されている方法ですが、`src/main/java`配下に

`public static void setDefault(Argument arg, Object dft)`

というメソッドを持つヘルパーclassを定義しておき、このJavaのclassをScalaから使用します。

[`/src/main/java/net/elehack/argparse4s/ArgConfig.java`](https://github.com/mdekstrand/argparse4s/blob/a9178bbdb90888e706da62ac06ac3aaabf07d909/src/main/java/net/elehack/argparse4s/ArgConfig.java)

```java
package net.elehack.argparse4s;

import net.sourceforge.argparse4j.inf.Argument;

class ArgConfig {
    public static void setDefault(Argument arg, Object dft) {
        arg.setDefault(dft);
    }
}
```

※このScalaラッパーライブラリ自体は、2019年現在メンテされていないようです

Answer (score 0):

一般的に完全に曖昧さを回避する方法があるか？というのは微妙ですが、今回のパターンなら、"型引数を取るか、取らないか？"という違いがあるため、型引数を明示することにより、(質問の直接の回答にはなっていませんが)可変長引数の方を呼ぶことは可能だとは思います。

```scala
scala> net.sourceforge.argparse4j.ArgumentParsers.newFor("a").build().addArgument("b").setDefault("c")
<console>:14: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method setDefault in trait Argument of type [E](x$1: E*)net.sourceforge.argparse4j.inf.Argument
and  method setDefault in trait Argument of type (x$1: Any)net.sourceforge.argparse4j.inf.Argument
match argument types (String)
       net.sourceforge.argparse4j.ArgumentParsers.newFor("a").build().addArgument("b").setDefault("c")
                                                                                       ^

scala> net.sourceforge.argparse4j.ArgumentParsers.newFor("a").build().addArgument("b").setDefault[String]("c")
res0: net.sourceforge.argparse4j.inf.Argument = net.sourceforge.argparse4j.internal.ArgumentImpl@736cb954
```

また、リフレクションで呼び出すにしても、わざと以下のようにstructural subtypingを使うと、多少短くかけて便利、などはあります。

```scala
.asInstanceOf[{def setDefault(x: AnyRef)}].setDefault("c")
```

Answer (score 0):

見ているところ、一般的な問題として見ると Scala の記述では明示的な解決方法はないようですね。
argparse4j のケースでは返値を使ってメソッドチェーンとして使用していますので、Structual Subtyping を implicit クラスで利用するようにしました。

```scala
implicit class _Argument(arg:Argument){
  def setDefault2(value:Any):Argument = {  // ← 名前は適当ですが
    import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
    arg.asInstanceOf[{def setDefault(value:Object):Argument}].setDefault(value)
  }
}
```